# "Transitioning" vs. "transitional" phase

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, american-english

I am wondering if it is correct to say:

> This is a transitioning phase.

Personally, I would say

> This is a transitional phase.

but my friend insists that the above is **just as correct** as my version.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct; however, the first is somewhat ambiguous (in that it could mean the *phase* is transitioning).  Hence it is much [less common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=transitional%20phase,transitioning%20phase&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=transitional+phase%2Ctransitioning+phase&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Since ambiguity should be guarded against whenever possible, my advice to you is: go on saying "transitional phase"!

Comment: Can you add a link to the NGram search results even if you include the image? It helps if I want to toy around with it a bit. :)

Comment: Just curious: what about a "transition phase"?

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, there's no problem -- any participle can be legally used as an adjective.

Is it as effective, insofar as language use?  I'd say not, because it's ambiguous -- what is "transitioning": items/processes inside the phase, or is the phase itself moving to something else (as in a workflow)?

If there's no chance it will be misunderstood, given its context, then fair enough -- but it never hurts to take no chances, so tell him it's safer to use "transitional".

Answer (score 0):

They probably convey similar meanings.  That suggests to me that *transitioning* is unnecessary, as is the use of *transition* as a verb; but, apart from being an annoying neologism, it is difficult to argue *transitioning phase* is incorrect.